# Changing time column to POSIXct without a date value

Tags: r, time, posixct

```
mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))
```

I'm currently trying to mutate my time variable to that instead of being a character variable, it is in the `as.POSIXct` format. But, everytime I apply this format, I always get this output: `2020-02-29 07:25:00`. The time normally looks like this in just the normal character form: `07:25:00` .

How do I get rid of the date??

Comment: `format(Time, "%T)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `hms` package ("hours minutes seconds").

```r
library(hms)

Time <- "2020-02-29 07:25:00"

as_hms(as.POSIXct(Time))
# 07:25:00
```

Comment: That did help change the column back to be time, but how can I make it an object of class `POSIXct`? I need it to be this class so I can use `scale_x_datetime` later on.

Comment: Do you need datetime? Or `scale_x_time()` for just the time?

Comment: Actually, yes, I only need time on the x-axis to be scaled. I'm just not sure how to use that function. `scale_x_time` sounds like what I would need to use though. I want the times to be 30 minutes apart from one another